# set apache as default server in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apache-2.4, ubuntu-16.04

first i installed apache on my local system, it working fine and then for some reason i installed nginx it also works fine, but now problem is each time when i start my system by default nginx is running on my system then i have to stop nginx using

> **sudo service nginx stop**

and then start apache manually by using

> **sudo service apache2 start**

but i want to change it to apache by default.

> **NOTE: I don't want to add any startup script.**

Answer (score 1):

you can change the listen directives for apache to port 80 and nginx to port 8080

on your `http.conf/apache.conf`

```
Listen 80
...
```

on your `nginx.conf`

```
Server {
    Listen 8080
    ...
```

Comment: > nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2018-11-16 13:22:34 IST; 36s ago

Comment: > apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: inactive (dead) since Fri 2018-11-16 13:22:39 IST; 39s ago

Comment: when i check status it gives above. nginx(running) and apache(dead)

Comment: do the following command: 
lsof -i TCP:80
then kill every process that running after that restart apache and nginx